# Парсер, ссылка меняется, страница отдается та же

Tags: python-3.x, beautiful-soup, urllib

Пишу парсер с помощью *beautifulsoup* и *urllib.request*.
Ссылку `get_html` получает каждый раз новую, но страницу выдает каждый раз старую.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

Base_url = 'http://www.petshop.ru/catalog/dogs/syxoi/'

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def find_max_page(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    #Поиск номера максимальной страницы
    number_nav = soup.find('div', class_='goods-nav')
    number_mass = [] # Хранилище для чисел
    for numbers in number_nav.find_all('a', attrs={'class':''}):
        number_mass.append(numbers.text)    
    #Поиск максимального числа в массиве
    max=0
    for i in range(0, len(number_mass)):
        number_mass[i] = int(number_mass[i])
        if (number_mass[i]>max): max=number_mass[i]
    return max

def parse_url(html):
    temp = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')  
    product_list = soup.find('div', id='products-wrapper')
    for product_link in product_list.find_all('a', class_='j_product-brand j_product-link'):
        temp.append('http://www.petshop.ru' + str(product_link.attrs['href']))
    return temp

def main():
    max = find_max_page(get_html(Base_url))
    urls = []   #Массив для ссылок
    for page in range(1, max+1):
        urls.extend(parse_url(get_html(Base_url + '#pn=%d' % page)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```